# MySQL After Update Trigger with Multiple Columns / Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get this trigger working:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER inv_update AFTER UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
UPDATE inventory
   SET ea_qty = CASE
                      WHEN id = ea_id THEN
        NEW.quantity,

box_qty = CASE
                     WHEN id = box_id THEN
        NEW.quantity
   END ;
END//

delimiter ;
```

I have also tried the following:

```
    delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER inv_update AFTER UPDATE ON products AS p FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
IF p.id = ea_id THEN
UPDATE inventory
  SET ea_qty = NEW.p.quantity
    END IF ;
IF p.id = box_id THEN
UPDATE inventory
   SET box_qty = NEW.p.quantity
     END IF ;

 END ;//

delimiter ;
```

**UPDATE**

What I'm trying to achieve is for every update in the products table, the corresponding id of the same product in the inventory table should be updated to keep the inventory and the product table in sync. e.g. after a sale occurs, product(s) affected will be less by the sales_item qty therefore there will be irregularities of the qty in the inventory table corresponding to that effect sales unless the inventory table is also updated. Meanwhile not all the product has a box_id in the inventory table. Relationships between ea_id and box_id is Parent to Child in both table but both is a separate id that sales can occur on.

I really hope am clear enough to get help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I make this just a guide for you, I dont know your table structure, im just imagining what you mean to be..

```
       delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER inv_update AFTER UPDATE ON products_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        declare ea_idvar int(20) default 0;
        declate box_idvar int(20) default 0;

        select ea_id,box_id INTO @ea_idvar,@box_idvar from products_table where product_id = old.product_id;

        if LENGTH(@ea_idvar)>0 THEN

                update inventory_table set ea_qty = new.ea_qty where product_id = new.product_id;

    elseif LENGTH(@box_idvar)>0 THEN

        update inventory_table set box_qty = new.box_qty where product_id = new.product_id;

    end if;
 END ;//

delimiter ;
```

if old is not working then change it to new.. good luck 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Im just creating a variable for ea_id.. need to ask something, where is it came from? ea_id and box_id can you explain this?where is it came from?

Comment: Thanks. ea_id and box_id are both "products" id inserted to "inventory" through association.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that everytime an update occur on the products table, the corresponding id of the same product in the inventory table should be updated to keep the inventory and the product table in sync. e.g. after a sale occurs, product(s) affected will be less by the sales_item qty therefore there will be irregularities of the qty in the inventory table corresponding to that effect sales unless the inventory table is also updated. Meanwhile not all the product has a box_id in the inventory table. Relationships between ea_id and box_id is Parent to Child. Thanks.

Comment: what table you are inserting?

Comment: ok thanks, first thing you want to do is update the inventory then update the products with same new id from inventory? just to be clear

Comment: Nope. What I want to do is update inventory after update on products

Comment: just give me the field name of the products to update and the field name and the where field name of the product to update.

Comment: Sorry. It seems you are not getting me.

Comment: got you, you are going to update products first then update inventory table all i want is the foriegn key of your inventory from product.. i need to know what is the field name.

Comment: I just want to use the new quantity inserted to product table everytime an update occur in the product table to update the quantity in the inventory table. We should not be concern about the product table at all. What we need from product is product->quantity to update inventory where Id is either in (box_id column or ea_id column)

Comment: how could i know if it is box_id or ea_id?

Comment: Ok. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Please note, the box_id and ea_id and product.id are all int not var. product.id = ea_id || box_id of integer value. Definitely != 0 and also is_unique.

Comment: It is a variable holding the fields from product table,, you can change it any  if you want.